# Android change orientation of ImageView

Tags: android, orientation, imageview

Is it possible to change the orientation of an ImageView to be always PORTRAIT, while the other views in the activity can rotate?

Since images don't always look good when rotated...

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think so. Orientation applies to activities, not views.